# Silverlight OOB Window Extend Aero Glass

Tags: wpf, silverlight, aero

I got a short and (I hope) easy Question.

Is it possible to extend the Aero Glass into a out of browser window in a Silverlight application? I guess the question is wether or not it can access DwmApi.dll...

Does anyone have a solution or clue to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is trusted, you could create a COM component to perform the behaviors you want.  In SL5, trusted applications will be able to directly call Win32 APIs.